# grid-area does not seem to work with the attr function, is this by design?

Tags: css, css-grid

The following works:

Note how I'm even using `content: attr(class)` to avoid having to type out the labels. Neat!

```css
section {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a1 a1 a1 a1" 
  "a2 a2 a3 a3" 
  "a2 a2 a4 a5" 
  "a6 a6 a6 a6" 
  "a7 a8 a9 a9" 
  "a7 a0 a0 a0";
}
.a1 { grid-area: a1; }
.a2 { grid-area: a2; }
.a3 { grid-area: a3; }
.a4 { grid-area: a4; }
.a5 { grid-area: a5; }
.a6 { grid-area: a6; }
.a7 { grid-area: a7; }
.a8 { grid-area: a8; }
.a9 { grid-area: a9; }
.a0 { grid-area: a0; }
div {
  display: flex;
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
div:before {
  margin: auto;
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="a1"></div>
 <div class="a2"></div>
 <div class="a3"></div>
 <div class="a4"></div>
 <div class="a5"></div>
 <div class="a6"></div>
 <div class="a7"></div>
 <div class="a8"></div>
 <div class="a9"></div>
 <div class="a0"></div>
</section>
```

Having to repeat those redundant `grid-area` declarations is a pain though. Perhaps I can use the same trick there?

```css
section {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a1 a1 a1 a1" 
  "a2 a2 a3 a3" 
  "a2 a2 a4 a5" 
  "a6 a6 a6 a6" 
  "a7 a8 a9 a9" 
  "a7 a0 a0 a0";
}

div {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: attr(class);
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
div:before {
  margin: auto;
  content: attr(class);
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="a1"></div>
 <div class="a2"></div>
 <div class="a3"></div>
 <div class="a4"></div>
 <div class="a5"></div>
 <div class="a6"></div>
 <div class="a7"></div>
 <div class="a8"></div>
 <div class="a9"></div>
 <div class="a0"></div>
</section>
```

Nope!

I've tried variations with doing a data attribute or including the unit type and still nothing. So what's going on here. Does `attr` not work with grid areas by design or is this a bug?

Tested in chrome, firefox, and safari latest on OsX. all to the same effect.

Comment: it's by design, attr() works only with content:

Comment: Where are you getting that @TemaniAfif ? In fact [the mdn page shows other usages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) and mentions no limitations

Comment: check at the bottom here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Specifications .. you will  find that the current spec (the last one in green) make it only limited to content .. the draft one contains other usage but still not supported yet

Comment: Oh, interesting. [English version for anyone else who is interested](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Specifications)

Comment: you can read this too : *Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental, and support for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.* [updated the link, wrongly pasted the French one]

Comment: That's sad, this is such a good use case... I could style and name everything with a single data attribute

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it's by design as `attr()` is acutally only suppored with `content`. As defined in [the current specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#x18) it's a value for `content`.

You can also read in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#Specifications):

> Note: The attr() function can be used with any CSS property, but support for properties other than content is experimental, and support for the type-or-unit parameter is sparse.

So it may work with other properties but this is still in *draft mode*

---

An alternative is to consider CSS variables where you will almost have the same thing to write but it will not work with `content` because it's not a string. For the content you can replace this with counters:

```css
section {
  outline: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "a1 a1 a1 a1" 
  "a2 a2 a3 a3" 
  "a2 a2 a4 a5" 
  "a6 a6 a6 a6" 
  "a7 a8 a9 a9" 
  "a7 a0 a0 a0";
    
  counter-reset:g;
}

div {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: var(--c);
  outline: 1px dotted green;
}
div:before {
  margin: auto;
  counter-increment: g;
  content: "a" counter(g);
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div style="--c:a1"></div>
 <div style="--c:a2"></div>
 <div style="--c:a3"></div>
 <div style="--c:a4"></div>
 <div style="--c:a5"></div>
 <div style="--c:a6"></div>
 <div style="--c:a7"></div>
 <div style="--c:a8"></div>
 <div style="--c:a9"></div>
 <div style="--c:a0"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you edit this to include your comment from above about `attr` only being supported for `content` now? Then it will be technically the answer and I'll accept

Comment: shame that using css variables is a bit harder with React than a custom attribute...