# Is it possible to pass CSS variable name through data attribute?

Tags: css, css-variables

What I'm looking for could work like this (it doesn't)

```
<span data-css-var="--my-css-var"></span>

:root {
  --my-css-var: some-color // created by js
}

span[data-css-var] {
  background-color: var(attr(data-css-var)) // error
}
```

The thing is I cannot set styles on the elem (3rd party), only data- attributes.
Any thoughts guys?
This one is read - https://css-tricks.com/css-attr-function-got-nothin-custom-properties/

Comment: Actually you cannot, maybe in the future. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613963/8620333

Comment: Here is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300536/get-value-of-attribute-in-css