# CSS attr() not working with -webkit-line-clamp

Tags: html, css, attributes, webkit

I would like to be able to set the number of lines to clamp using an attribute named `data-lines`.

This code DOES NOT work:

```css
[data-lines] {
    overflow : hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: attr(data-lines);
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p data-lines="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
```

This code DOES work:

```css
[data-lines] {
    overflow : hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<p data-lines="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.</p>
```

Comment: attr() works only with content at the time being

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56613963/8620333 .. you mat consider CSS variables